# problem when i run my application spring boot when i want to connect mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaautoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property: org.sid.cinema.entities.Seance.her Debut
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.
```

Comment: Can you add relevant code where `@Temporal` is used by editing the question

Answer (score 0):

I met with this problem before. This happens when you import from wrong package.

Use

```
import java.sql.Date;
```

instead of

```
import java.util.Date;
```

Hope this is helpful.